# meteor reporting of data in existing mysql db. how?

Tags: mysql, database, meteor, reporting

I'm trying to make some reports using meteor and raphael js. I have to report data from an existing MySQL database. I do not wish to write to that database. I need only the "R" from CRUD.
I have thought of various manual ways of: exporting .csv files from the MySQL db via the application itself (Limesurvey) and using `mongoimport` to populate a MongoDB collection, and then do my `CollectionName.find()` etc in Meteor.
or perhaps some way of exposing REST full endpoints only to consume data, and use the http package for Meteor.

Is there a good clean solution for using existing SQL data in a Meteor JS application?
How can one use pre-existing SQL data?

(I've no problem with duplication in MongoDB, mind you. however it has to be...)
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* do it without any duplication completely from inside Meteor, but you will have to jump through a couple of hoops.

Firstly, use the [`mysql` npm package](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) to query the SQL database. Though Meteor provides `Npm` to `require` node packages, I find that using `meteor-npm` is an easier. Then to do the "R"eading form MySQL, create a `Meteor.method` on your server which queries the MySQL directly.

Then the second problem is that the `mysql` package is completely asynchronous. Hence, the execution of the SQL query returns value in a call back and by that point, your `Meteor.method` call would return leaving the client with an `undefined.` To fix that issue, we can use `Future`.

There are a couple of ways of smoothing over this step:

1. Using [`meteor-sync-methods](https://github.com/ianserlin/meteor-sync-methods)
2. Spinning out your own version from advice from [the issue to allow this natively](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/74)
3. Use this easy to implement one-time pattern: ["fence has already activated -- too late to add writes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485904/fence-has-already-activated-too-late-to-add-writes/11510874#11510874)

Hope that helps.

Comment: wow cool, thanks for that. I'll give your 3rd option a shot first, although the Meteor.syncMethods package looks interesting.